# Content overflows even though height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, styles, height

I know there is a lot of discussions out there regarding `height: 100%` in CSS but I have a rather direct one. Observe this small fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkcm1bu7/.

There are three elements, `html`, `body` and `div`. All of them have their height set at `100%`. This works as intended:

[image]

**But** if I reduce the viewport's height, so that the content does not fit and a vertical scroll bar appears, the content seems to overflow its parent container:

[image]

Could anyone please explain me why this happens and how to solve this? I've been messing around for this behavior for quite a while and it is really frustrating. Setting `min-height: 100%` on the body solves this problem but in non-trivial layouts create other issues.

Comment: have you tried adding `overflow` in your CSS to the div? as long as the content exists, browsers will try to show it, sometimes you need to "force" the browser to hide excess content `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Actually not sure why this behavior happens, but if you use `*` it will change everything, also outside 'html-boundaries'.

Comment: why dont you use height: auto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because when you set the height of the `html`, `body` and `div` to be 100% you're setting to reference the viewport (browser window). When the viewport height is resized to it's minimum height and the content is larger it spills out of it's container. You can solve this by setting the [overflow property to a number of different values](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/).

I have opted below to set it to auto:

```css
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 html {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 50px; /*I have set this to 50px to show off how overflow works*/
 }
 
 
 body {
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 
 div {
 overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
      <p>sometext</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay... And I was under the impression that `overflow: auto` is the default one (the default one is `visible`).

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned in a comment, but I checked your fiddle and adding `overflow:hidden;` to the div CSS resolves the issue.

Comment: Doesn't really resolve the issue, it cuts off the content and allows the content to overflow, which hides the vertical the scroll bar